# Mutual Information between discrete and continuous variable in deep learning

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, machine-learning, information-theory

I was trying to replicate an experiment from "[When does label smoothing help?](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8717-when-does-label-smoothing-help.pdf)" in NeurIPS, 2019. The experiment is related to calculating the mutual information between input image to a neural network $X$ (discrete variable), and the difference between network output logits of two classes $Y$ (Continuous variable). The source of randomness comes from data augmentation in $X$ and we approximate the distribution of $Y$ as a Gaussian and they estimate the mean and variance from the examples using Monte Carlo samples. The approximated formula is given as below where the output should be some value between $0$, and $log(N)$

$\begin{aligned}
&I(X ; Y)=E_{X, Y}\left[\log (p(y | x))-\log \left(\sum_{x} p(y | x)\right)\right] \text { and }\\
&\hat{I}(X ; Y)=\sum_{x=1}^{N}\left[-\left(f\left(d\left(\boldsymbol{z}_{x}\right)\right)-\mu_{x}\right)^{2} /\left(2 \sigma^{2}\right)-\log \left(\sum_{x=1}^{N} e^{-\left(f\left(d\left(\boldsymbol{z}_{x}\right)\right)-\mu_{x}\right)^{2} /\left(2 \sigma^{2}\right)}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}$

where $\mu_{x}=\sum_{l=1}^{L} f\left(d\left(\boldsymbol{z}_{x}\right)\right) / L, \sigma^{2}=\sum_{x=1}^{N}\left(f\left(d\left(\boldsymbol{z}_{x}\right)\right)-\mu_{x}\right)^{2} / N, L$ is the number of Monte Carlo
samples used to calculate the empirical mean and $N$ is the number of training examples used for mutual information estimation.

My questions: 
1. I don't really understand how this approximation is done and they didn't explain or cite this part. So, any hints will be appreciated.
2. While replicating the same formula, the output mutual information is something around -4000, I'm not totally sure that the formula is totally correct but substituting some rough estimated numbers inside it won't end up with something in the range from $0$ to $log(N)$. Did they forget some normalization constants in their approximated formula?

Comment: I'm not very sure but for a discrete variable $X$ with $N$ possible values, both $0 \leq H(X) \leq log(N)$ and $H(X|Y) \leq H(X)$ hold. Hence $0 \leq I(X, Y)=H(X) - H(X|Y) \leq log(N)$. I think their approximation can be seen formally as the mutual information between some discrete variables.

Comment: I was trying to give an answer when i've noticed that there is a typos in the paper $\mu_x=\sum_{l=1}^{L}\frac{f(d(z_x))}L$ do not depend on $l$.

Comment: However, based on the approximated detailed formula they wrote, it can't be a positive value. That's why I'm trying to understand how they came up with this approximate so I can figure out what are the missing terms in the formula if any.

Regarding ur 2nd comment, you are indeed correct but it is still quite understandable what they means.